# How to override the 'create' method when inserting into a related model. Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, overriding

I want to insert a new event (like a party ...etc) that is related to a user, so I do this according to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) tutorial. This is inside `EventsService.php`.

```
public function store( StoreEventRequest $request, $dashboard = false ) {
    $owner = User::find( $request->owner_id );
    try {

        $event = $owner->events()->create( $request->all() );

    } catch ( \Exception $exception ) {
        throw new Exception( $exception->getMessage() );
    }
    $this->interestsService->updateFromRequest( $event );

    if ( $request->hasFile( 'photos' ) ) {
        $event->photosFromRequest( $request );
    }

    if ( $request->hasFile( 'cover_photo' ) ) {
        $event->coverPhotoFromRequest( $request );
    }

    return $event->fresh();
}
```

I added the `filterByPrivacy()` inside `StoreEventRequest.php` as suggested by the answer:

```
public function filterByPrivacy()
    {
        error_log(('Im here.'));
        if ($this->privacy == "private") {
        $this->request->set('access_code', $this->getAccessCodeAttribute());
        }

    else {

        $this->request->set('access_code', null);
    }


}
```

The issue is that `error_log(('Im here.'));` never gets printed, other methods inside the same class do.

Comment: First off I would strongly advice not to pass all input from the request directly into the create method. You could use only to get just items you are interested in. Rather than overwrite create method I would probably use designated request class and process all the logic from within. I’ll write some example code in a moment to illustrate.

Comment: Can you also add the contents of your `StoreEventRequest` file here? It might be that the validation rules (if any present) are failing and you never get to call `filterByPrivacy`.

Comment: You could also add route model binding to your `RouteServiceProvider` and have instance of `User` injected to your method rather than doing it manually (just a thought).

Comment: My answer has now been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do - and my assumption is that you're trying to create those events from within the controller (correct me if I'm wrong):

First create a new request for this specific action:

```
php artisan make:request StoreEventRequest
```

This will add a new request file `app/Http/Requests/StoreEventRequest.php`

Suggested structure of the request file (please replace comments to put what you require):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreEventRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        // this should probably be handled by middleware           
        $user = $this->user();

        return $user && ($user->isAdmin() || $user->isActive());
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        $rules = [
            'id' => 'exists:events,id',
            'name' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|max:1000',
            'city_id' => 'exists:cities,id',
            'country_id' => 'exists:countries,id',
            'location_address' => 'required|string',
            'location_latitude' => 'latitude',
            'location_longitude' => 'longitude',
            'privacy' => 'in:public,private',
            'budget' => 'numeric|min:0',
            'photos.*' => 'image',
            'cover_photo' => 'image',
            'min_attendees' => 'integer|min:0',
            'max_attendees' => 'integer|min:0',
            'starts_at' => 'required|date|after:now',
            'ends_at' => 'required|date|after:starts_at',
        ];

        if ($this->user()->isAdmin()) {

            //administrator special validation and overrides
            $rules['description'] = 'max:5000';
            $rules['location_address'] = 'string';
        }

        return $rules;
    }

    /**
     * Get processed request data.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function data(): array
    {
        $data = array_merge(
            $this->only([
                'id',
                'name',
                'description',
                'city_id',
                'country_id',
                'location_address',
                'location_latitude',
                'location_longitude',
                'privacy',
                'budget',
                'photos.*',
                'cover_photo',
                'min_attendees',
                'max_attendees',
                'starts_at',
                'ends_at',
            ]),
            [
                'access_code' => null
            ]
        );

        if ($data['privacy'] === "private") {
            $data['access_code'] = $this->accessCode();
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get access code.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function accessCode(): int
    {
        return rand(1000, 99999);
    }
}
```

I'm working on the assumption that `owner_id` is present in the route:

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::post('event/{owner_id}/store', 'EventController@store')->name('event.store');

// app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('owner_id', User::class);
}
```

This way our controller's method has it available directly as a dependency (I've removed your `try/catch` as it doesn't seem to do anything other than re-throwing itself):

```php
public function store(StoreEventRequest $request, User $owner, $dashboard = false)
{
    $event = $owner->events()->create($request->data());

    $this->interestsService->updateFromRequest($event);

    if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {
        $event->photosFromRequest($request);
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('cover_photo')) {
        $event->coverPhotoFromRequest($request);
    }

    return $event->fresh();
}
```

I wasn't sure where `$dashboard` argument is coming from so left it there, but I believe that'll also be registered on the route.

A quick test that would give you a bit more of an insight on what might be failing:

```
php artisan make:test EventTest
```

and its contents:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class EventTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function passes_validation()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->post(route('event.store', $user->id), [
            // ... your request data goes here
        ]);

        // update response status to whatever you expect it to be
        // I've used 201 for CREATED
        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }
}
```

This way you have all data prepared the way you need it for the `create` method - without necessity of overwriting it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm dealing with legacy code. I did find the AddNewEventRequest and added the filter function as public function but the code does not go through it. it goes through all other function inside the AddNewEventRequest though. I'll add more details just now.

Comment: Ok - if you add more code, it should be easier to see what your actual set up is.

Comment: Great - please see my comment below it - if you could post content of your request file as I believe that's where the issue is.

Comment: I added the request file.

Comment: Great - I'll try to decipher it and update my response. Do you have any tests written for this case?

Answer (score 1):

In your model, create a boot method and use `creating` static function that will execute before create method call:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($model)
    {
        dd($model);
    });
}
```

Comment: if its right then mark as correct so other developer can get their solution